# pip install mysqlclient through s ,failed to import Cython: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Tags: python, mysql, django

Hi iam following [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/), earlier i thought of using oracle db,but not got right documentation thus decided to use mysql db. Iam following with **django version 1.8** and **python 2.7.12**(both are compatible).I have installed **mysql 5.7.19.0** .

When i run `pip install mysqlclient`,iam getting below error,

```
 copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  failed to import Cython: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
  error: Cython does not appear to be installed
```

But i can see that Cython is already installed,when i type `pip install cython`.I am using **64 bit windows machine and installed python 2.7.2(64 bit)**.How can i resolve this? Please let me know any other documentation available for setting **MySql db with(django version 1.8+python 2.7.12)**?Serched over web but could not able to resolve this.

Comment: are you able to do `import Cython` in python shell?

Comment: Why are you trying to use Cython at all?

Comment: @Daniel,No i just want to come out of this error so i tried reinstalling cython but its alredy inslalled

Comment: @Arpit,yes i can able to import Cython in shell

Comment: you said you are using 64 bit pc and python, but from the error its clear that the version is for 32 bit machines, are you running the install from terminal directly or you have downloaded mysqlclient wheel and trying to install it?

Comment: @Exprator,Iam installing it from cmd through, pip install mysqlclient command.If its problem with mysqlclient 32 bit being installed,how can i specify in coomand to install mysqlclient 64 bit?